how to store randomized secret key in fastapi?
I am creating login system using FAstAPI. where Instead of hard coding secret_key, or storing unsecurely somewhere, I am randomizing secret key as below.
secret_key = secrets.token_hex(32)
now, I want to use middleware to access this secret_key directly from the header after login is successful, But after login when I try to execute get_crrent_user endpoint it's asking me for secret_key as query parameter. I want it to take it directly from middleware. need help in this.
below is my crud.py file code.
app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


class SecretKeyMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, secret_key: str):
        self.secret_key = secret_key

    async def __call__(self, request: Request, response: Response):
        # Add the secret key to the request state
        request.state.secret_key = self.secret_key
        # Continue processing the request
        response = await self.app(request, response)
        return response

# Password hashing context
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")
secret_key = secrets.token_hex(32)
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login")

# Add the middleware to your FastAPI app
app.middleware("http")(SecretKeyMiddleware(secret_key))


def create_access_token(user):
    print("User: ", user.username)
    try:
        claims = {
            "sub": user.username,
            "password": user.password,
            "exp": datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(days=30),
            "is_active" : True
        }
        TokenData.secret_key = secret_key
        return jwt.encode(claims, key=secret_key, algorithm="HS256")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        raise ex
    

def verify_token(token, secret_key: str = Depends(SecretKeyMiddleware)):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, key=secret_key, algorithms=["HS256"])
        return payload
    except:
        raise Exception('Wrong Token')
    

def check_active(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme), secret_key: str = Depends(SecretKeyMiddleware)):
    try:
        payload = verify_token(token, secret_key)
        exp_timestamp = payload.get('exp', None)
        # If exp_timestamp is None or token is expired
        if exp_timestamp is None or datetime.now(timezone.utc) > datetime.fromtimestamp(exp_timestamp, timezone.utc):
            raise Exception('Token is Expired. login again')  # Token is expired
        else:
            return payload  # Token is valid
        
    except jwt.DecodeError:
        return False  # Token is invalid or expired



# Middleware to validate JWT token
def get_current_user(token: dict = Depends(check_active), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        # Decode the JWT token
        email = token.get("sub")
        # user_id = payload.get("id")

        if email:
            user = get_user_by_email(db, email=email)
        elif email:
            user = get_user_by_id(db, id=email)
        else:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Token does not contain valid user information",
            )

        if user is None:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="User not found",
            )

        return user
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Token has expired",
        )
    except jwt.JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid token",
        )

I am also attaching auth.py file's login logic
@router.post("/login/")
def login(form_data : OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if validate_email(form_data.username):
        user = get_user_by_email(db, email=form_data.username)
    else:
        user = get_user_by_id(db, id=form_data.username)
    # Check if the user exists in the database
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Incorrect id or email")

    # Verify the password
    if not verify_password(form_data.password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Incorrect password")

    # If username and password are valid, return a success message
    access_token = create_access_token(form_data)
    return {"success": True, "message": "Login successful", "access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

and lastly I am attaching user.py's get current user request for your better understanding.
@router.post("/login/")
def login(form_data : OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if validate_email(form_data.username):
        user = get_user_by_email(db, email=form_data.username)
    else:
        user = get_user_by_id(db, id=form_data.username)
    # Check if the user exists in the database
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Incorrect id or email")

    # Verify the password
    if not verify_password(form_data.password, user.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Incorrect password")

    # If username and password are valid, return a success message
    access_token = create_access_token(form_data)
    return {"success": True, "message": "Login successful", "access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}


Be aware that this means that you can't ever have more than a single worker to handle your users (so you can't really effectively handle more than what a single thread can handle) except if you use a frontend proxy with sticky sessions, and that you'll end with everyone having to reauthenticate if you restart your server. But the error is caused by SecretKeyMiddleware requiring an argument when creating the class, so your dependency has no idea how to provide that except for from a query argument.

Thanks @MatsLindh for answer. should I just define a secret key in my env?

Yes, depending on usage, that's how you'll have to do it. If the JWT is generated by a separate service, you can use a private key to sign the token and a public key to verify it, but otherwise you'll need both in the same service regardless, so using a single secret would work fine.

but won't it be less secure ? Anyway Thanks for Answer @MatsLindth

Security isn't absolute, it's always a trade-off in some way. If an attacker is able to get your secret key disclosed - what other part is they able to access? Do you need a JWT at all instead of just a session token (divulging the active session token is just the same token as the user submitted)?

I am using JWT as session Token.

Yes, but a JWT is based on the actual information you trust being sent to the client. If you instead assign a randomly generated session token and keep the information you trust server side, you won't have any issue with trying to keep the specific key secret - the user already has that key (the session token); and a random key has been generated for every user, instead of having a key sign each user's JWT. A JWT is a way to solve specific problems, especially when authentication and application are two separate services.

Thanks for the information. I truly appreciate your time and knowledge.

can you provide me an example for above as
I am just starting and little bit lost.
